# Analogs of universal coverings for vector bundles

Tags: vector-bundles, universal-property

Not sure if I should use the [soft-question](/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag here. Decided to wait with it :D

The universal covering of a (nice enough) space $X$ is a universal, in a suitable sense, representation of $X$ in the form $\tilde X/G$ where $\tilde X$ is a simply connected space and $G$ acts freely on $\tilde X$.

Suppose given a vector bundle $E\to B$, with fibre a vector space $V$. Under which conditions is there a similar representation of it as $\pi/G:(\tilde B\times V)/G\to\tilde B/G$ where $\pi:\tilde B\times V\to\tilde B$ is the trivial vector bundle, with $G$ and $\tilde B$ determined uniquely up to isomorphism by some universal property?

The question makes sense both for topological and algebraic vector bundles.

Comment: This looks like a tautology. What about $B\times_{BO}EO$ (or whatever the structure group is) with the induced (obviously trivial) vector bundle? I presume that this is the same as pulling $E$ back to the corresponding principal bundle.

Comment: $B\times_{BO}EO$ must be $E$, do you mean $E\times_BE\to E$, with $\tilde B=E$? What would be the universal property? And, how does the principal bundle fit in here?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by a vector bundle. $EO\to BO$ is the **principal** tautological bundle (by definition); if your $E$ is also principal, then yes, I mean $E$. For "universal", take your favorite universal property of $EO\to BO$ and restate it in terms of $E\to B$.